# how to compare two string variables in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have two string columns in my Pandas dataset

```
name1     name2
John Doe  John Doe
AleX T    Franz K
```

and I need to check whether `name1` equals `name2`.
The naive way I use now is using a simple mask

`mask=df.name1==df.name2`

But the problem is that there may be mislabeled strings (in a way that is not predictable - the data is too big) that prevent an exact matching to occur.

For instance "John Doe" and "John   Doe " would not match. Of course, I trimmed, lower-cased my strings but other possibilities remain.

One idea would be to look whether `name1` is contained in `name2`. But it seems I cannot use `str.contains` with another variable as argument. Any other ideas?

Many thanks!

EDIT: using `isin` gives non-sensical results.
Example

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'A': ["john doe", " john doe", 'John'], 'B': [' john doe', 'eddie murphy', 'batman']})

test
Out[6]: 
           A             B
0   john doe      john doe
1   john doe  eddie murphy
2       John        batman

test['A'].isin(test['B'])
Out[7]: 
0    False
1     True
2    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Hi @edchum this is not a duplicate of the question you mention.

Comment: So are you after something like `df['name1'].str.lower() == df['name2'].str.lower()`?

Comment: not really, because I believe perfect equality generate too many false negatives in the data. checking whether name1 is contained somewhere in name2 seems more appropriate

Comment: I think in this case you should `strip` the spaces and `lower` the case, see my answer

Comment: If you proposed using something like `in` then you'd have to do this using `apply` like `df.apply(lambda x: x['A'].strip().lower() in x['B'].strip().lower(), axis=1)`

Comment: `.isin()` does **not** give nonsensical results, it does exactly what the doc says; if you do `.isin(test['B'])`, you're comparing each LHS to the entire column `test['B']` (the entire series) not just an individual row-by-row comparison (for which you'd have to do an `.apply(..., axis=1)`) with a lambda fn. (Although, that's a good [pandas docbug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues) catch.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can use [`str.lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) and [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with arbitrary whitespace `s/+`:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'A': ["john  doe", " john doe", 'John'], 
                     'B': [' john doe', 'eddie murphy', 'batman']})

print test['A'].str.lower().str.replace('s/+',"") == 
      test['B'].str.strip().str.replace('s/+',"")


0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: I dont understand why this gives me non-sensical results. please see my updated question

Comment: do you have any ideas whats going on with `isin` here?

Comment: Sorry, I was offline.

Answer (score 5):

You can use difflib to compute distance

```
import difflib as dfl
dfl.SequenceMatcher(None,'John Doe', 'John doe').ratio()
```

edit : integration with Pandas :

```
import pandas as pd
import difflib as dfl
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ["john doe", " john doe", 'John'], 'B': [' john doe', 'eddie murphy', 'batman']})
df['VAR1'] = df.apply(lambda x : dfl.SequenceMatcher(None, x['A'], x['B']).ratio(),axis=1)
```

Comment: does that integrate with pandas dataframes?

Answer (score 4):

`strip` the spaces and `lower` the case:

```
In [414]:
test['A'].str.strip().str.lower() == test['B'].str.strip().str.lower()

Out[414]:
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a string distance based on editing effort `distance(s1, s2)`, which is what we call `edit distance of strings`. Once you define that function in your namespace you can do:

```
df['distance_s'] = df.apply(lambda r: distance(r['name1'], r['name2']))
filtered = df[df['distance_s'] < eps] # you define eps
```

From a Google search, the following came up:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/editdistance

It is a dynamic programming problem, so you can challenge yourself by writing your own too. It may not be as efficient though.